# dompdf bootstrap table first value is shown in the second column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dompdf, bootstrap-table

I am using Dompdf to export a table report to PDF, the table looks ок in HTML as follows (an example is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_basic&stacked=h)):

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The problem is that, when exported to PDF, the very first value of the table is offset to the second column... like this:

```
<tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td> {#NOTHING HERE#}
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>john@example.com</td>{#Now everything is offset#}
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
      </tr>
     <td>july@example.com</td>{#And this goes outside the table#}
    </tbody>
```

The dompdf version is `0.7.x@beta`.

I even try to convert the table with [this site](http://divtable.com/converter/) to `divs` and it ouputs yet another error!

Why is this happening??? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in dompdf versions prior to 0.7.0, see [issue #1103](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1103).

Comment: Actually, I am trying with `0.7.x@beta` It is not working :(

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34930517/1883256) makes the table look properly.

Comment: FYI, 0.7.0 final is just about to be released. It includes a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

this remove some empty spaces, try:

```
thead:before, thead:after { display: none; }
tbody:before, tbody:after { display: none; }
```